# Simple way of DebugPrint function creation with cout in c++

Tags: c++, cout

Is there some simple way of creation of DebugPrint function, based on cout, which will accept all datatypes supported by cout.

I tried

```
void DebugPrint(void * data)
{
  cout<<data<<endl;
}
```

However it is not working.

Comment: Use a [template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template).

Comment: use `cerr` when printing error information. `cout` should only be used for information that is intended for the User

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use templates:

```
template<class T> inline void DebugPrint( const T& data )
{
   cout << data << endl;
}
```

or macros:

```
#define DebugPrint( data ) cout << data << endl;
```

templates are always preferable...macro must be avoided (in general).

Comment: Please, no macros in C++. Really.

Comment: Does `const T & data` would be better?

Comment: Yeah, there's no reason at all to make that function a macro, especially one that [doesn't work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a240e720c995be3) and has a name that doesn't stand out.